# Rabbit ToggleClass is not working properly

Tags: jquery

I have an image gallery for which I would like to be able to click on the little "plus" at the bottom right of the image to display a text on the image. I also want the text to disappear when I click on another image.
If I click on the "+", the text appears as desired. If I click on another image, it disappears so it's ok. However, my problem is that I can't show the text and then hide it by clicking on the "+" of the same image.
Do you have any ideas to solve this bug?
Thanks in advance for your lights

```js
$(".more").click(function(){     
    $('.fermer').not(this).removeClass('fermer');
    $('.apparait').not(this).removeClass('apparait');
    $(this).toggleClass ('fermer');
    $(this).next(".infos").toggleClass('apparait');
   });
```

```css
.more {position: absolute; font-size:35px; color:white; bottom: 5px; right: 40px; z-index: 10;cursor: pointer;}
.more.fermer {transform: rotate(+45deg); color:black}
.infos {opacity:0;width: 100%;height: 100%;position: absolute;overflow: hidden;top: 0;left: 0; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; pointer-events:none; padding: 20px; z-index: 9;}
.infos.apparait{opacity:1!important;transition: all .5s; }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">  
    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
          <img src="http://placerabbit.com/200/200/" width="200" height="200" alt="" class="open"/>
    <div class="more">+</div>
    <div class="infos">
   <h3>Title</h3>
   <p>Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla </p> 
      </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="col-sm-4 ">
          <img src="http://placerabbit.com/200/200/" width="200" height="200" alt="" class="open"/>
    <div class="more">+</div>
    <div class="infos">
   <h3>Title</h3>
   <p>Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla </p> 
      </div>
    </div>
    
        <div class="col-sm-4 ">
          <img src="http://placerabbit.com/200/200/" width="200" height="200" alt="" class="open"/>
    <div class="more">+</div>
    <div class="infos">
   <h3>Title</h3>
   <p>Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla </p> 
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: You could use `hasClass` to determine if class already exists in div: https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tested with if hasClass but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want that the more button has a fermer class toggled, and also the next element, so I think doing this alone should be ok:

```
$(".more").click(function(){
    //To clean the classes
    $(".more").not(this).removeClass('fermer');     
    $(".more").not(this).next().removeClass('apparait');

    $(this).toggleClass('fermer');
    $(this).next(".infos").toggleClass('apparait');
});
```

That is using your code, otherwise a better approach can be something like:

```
$('.more').click(function(){
    //To clean the classes
    $('.more').not(this).removeClass('fermer').next().removeClass('apparait');
    $(this).toggleClass('fermer').next().toggleClass('apparait');
});
```

Comment: Thank you Leo for your response! 
Your solution is perfect to show and hide the text over an image but I would also that when you click on the "+" of another image it removes the class .apparait on the previous image.

Comment: Ah ok didn't saw the other functionality part, there, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Leo for your modifications, it works now perfectly well! Have a nice day!